# Undefined when selecting div with information

Tags: reactjs

Having an issue with a piece of my code.  I fetch from flask server, and display with div in React.  I want to select the div and have that information pass to a new object array to return back to flask, but I keep getting undefined.

Code snippet:

```
function PLCPage() {
  const [myjunk, setMyjunk] =  useState([]);
  const [devList, setDevList] = useState ([]);

  const Scan = () => {
    fetch('/api/home').then(response => {
      if(response.status === 200){
        return response.json()
      }
    })
    .then(data => setMyjunk(data))
    .then(error => console.log(error))
  }

  const Clear = () => {
    setMyjunk({})
  }
```

Creating the divs:

```
{Object.keys(myjunk).map((key) =>{
  return ( 
    <div className='plc-container' key={key} onClick={ReadStuff}>
      <h1>ID:{myjunk[key]['name']}</h1> 
      <h1>IP:{myjunk[key]['IP']}</h1>                      
    </div>
  )
```

Clicking on the div, just to return a console log returns undefined.

```
const ReadStuff = () => {
  console.log(this.IP)
}
```

I eventually want to return the data I have in the 2 h1 tags to a new object (devList) but I can't even get it to console log.  Sorry if this is basic but I've been stumped at this for a week.  Thanks

I've tried this.IP, myjunk.IP, this,myjunk.IP.  myjunk['IP'].  Nothing returns.  And when I do myjunk.IP I get "cant read from undefined"

Comment: "I eventually want to return the data I have in the 2 h1 tags to a new object" Sounds like you need to study React fundaments. In Reach we don't "return data" from any HTML elements. Instead, we use state to manage data and pass it around as props.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a separate component:

```
const JunkButton = ({junk}) => (
    <div className='plc-container' key={key} onClick={() => ReadStuff(junk)}>
        <h1>ID:{junk['name']}</h1> 
        <h1>IP:{junk['IP']}</h1>
    </div>
)
```

Now your `map()` looks like:

```
{Object.keys(myjunk).map((key) =>{ <JunkButton junk={ myjunk[key] }/> }
```

And `ReadStuff` becomes:

```
const ReadStuff = (junk) => { console.log(junk) }
```

Notice how in React we explicitly pass things around as props or function parameters.

Comment: Definitely need to revisit props then.  Thank you!

Comment: @Destrier In this case, it's mostly about explicitly passing data around rather than trying to use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to pass `myjuck` to function and then console it like this:

```
{Object.keys(myjunk).map((key) =>{
          return (
    // sending myjuck to function whatever that is
            <div className='plc-container' key={key} onClick={() => ReadStuff(myjunk)}>
              <h1>ID:{myjunk[key]['name']}</h1> 
              <h1>IP:{myjunk[key]['IP']}</h1>                      
            </div>
          )
```

ReadStuff function

```
   const ReadStuff = (myjunk) => { console.log(tmyjunk) }
```

Comment: Ahh I see.  I'm starting to understand.  Thanks!